# Highlight/find data points in plotly scatter from the browser

Tags: r, plotly, scatter

I generated a scatterplot in HTML format using plotly and a generic dataframe. I am aware that it is possible to highlight (with a different color for example) certain data points *before* generating the plot HTML. However, I wonder if it is possible to add an element to the HTML file that would enable a user to find/highlight a certain data point based on its text label after the plot has been produced.

The code I used to produce the dataframe and scatter:

```
tab <- data.frame(sample.id = pca$sample.id,
                  EV1 = pca$eigenvect[, 1],
                  EV2 = pca$eigenvect[, 2],
                  stringsAsFactors=F)

p <- plot_ly(tab, x=tab$EV1, y=tab$EV2, text=tab$sample.id)
p <- layout(p, title="PCA", xaxis=list(title="PC 1"),
          yaxis=list(title="PC 2"))

htmlwidgets::saveWidget(as.widget(p), paste(output_name, ".html", sep=""))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know there is not builtin functionality in Plotly but you just need a few lines of Javascript code to get the functionality.

Plotly stores the data in a `application/json` object in the HTML file. You can get the data via

```
var data = JSON.parse(document.querySelectorAll("script[type='application/json']")[0].innerHTML);
```

The text elements are stored in

```
data.x.data[i].text[j]
```

where `i` is the trace number and `j` is point number.

Now we need a text field and a button, we can use `htmltools` for that purpose

```
p <- htmlwidgets::appendContent(p, htmltools::tags$input(id='inputText', value='Merc', ''), htmltools::tags$button(id='buttonSearch', 'Search'))
```

Let's add a eventlister to the button which triggers a [hover event](https://plot.ly/javascript/hover-events/) of the first point of the first trace.

```
p <- htmlwidgets::appendContent(p, htmltools::tags$script(HTML(
  'document.getElementById("buttonSearch").addEventListener("click", function() 
    {
    var myDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("js-plotly-plot")[0]
    Plotly.Fx.hover(myDiv, [{curveNumber: 0, pointNumber: 0}]);
    }
  )
')))
```

And the whole code which searches for through all text labels and triggers a hover event when the entered text is found in the label.

[image]

```
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(htmltools)

pcaCars <- princomp(mtcars, cor = TRUE)
carsHC <- hclust(dist(pcaCars$scores), method = "ward.D2")

carsDf <- data.frame(pcaCars$scores, "cluster" = factor(carsClusters))
carsClusters <- cutree(carsHC, k = 3)

carsDf <- transform(carsDf, cluster_name = paste("Cluster", carsClusters))

p <- plot_ly(carsDf, x = ~Comp.1 , y = ~Comp.2, text = rownames(carsDf),
             mode = "markers", color = ~cluster_name, marker = list(size = 11), type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers')

p <- htmlwidgets::appendContent(p, htmltools::tags$input(id='inputText', value='Merc', ''), htmltools::tags$button(id='buttonSearch', 'Search'))
p <- htmlwidgets::appendContent(p, htmltools::tags$script(HTML(
  'document.getElementById("buttonSearch").addEventListener("click", function()
    {        
      var i = 0;
     var j = 0;
      var found = [];
      var myDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("js-plotly-plot")[0]
      var data = JSON.parse(document.querySelectorAll("script[type=\'application/json\']")[0].innerHTML);
      for (i = 0 ;i < data.x.data.length; i += 1) {
        for (j = 0; j < data.x.data[i].text.length; j += 1) {
          if (data.x.data[i].text[j].indexOf(document.getElementById("inputText").value) !== -1) {
            found.push({curveNumber: i, pointNumber: j});
          }
        }
      }
      Plotly.Fx.hover(myDiv, found);
    }  
  );')))                                                    

htmlwidgets::saveWidget(p, paste('pca', ".html", sep=""))
p
```

The PCA implementation was modified from [here](http://moderndata.plot.ly/principal-component-analysis-cluster-plotly/).

Comment: Awesome. This was exactly what I needed. Thank you very much.