# R: Adding a Search Bar to Plotly

Tags: javascript, r, plotly

I found this stackoverflow post over here ([Highlight/find data points in plotly scatter from the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42507096/highlight-find-data-points-in-plotly-scatter-from-the-browser)) in which they show how to create a search bar for a scatterplot in plotly.

I tried to run the code provided in this example:

```
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(htmltools)

pcaCars <- princomp(mtcars, cor = TRUE)
carsHC <- hclust(dist(pcaCars$scores), method = "ward.D2")

carsDf <- data.frame(pcaCars$scores, "cluster" = factor(carsClusters))
carsClusters <- cutree(carsHC, k = 3)

carsDf <- transform(carsDf, cluster_name = paste("Cluster", carsClusters))

p <- plot_ly(carsDf, x = ~Comp.1 , y = ~Comp.2, text = rownames(carsDf),
             mode = "markers", color = ~cluster_name, marker = list(size = 11), type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers')

p <- htmlwidgets::appendContent(p, htmltools::tags$input(id='inputText', value='Merc', ''), htmltools::tags$button(id='buttonSearch', 'Search'))
p <- htmlwidgets::appendContent(p, htmltools::tags$script(HTML(
  'document.getElementById("buttonSearch").addEventListener("click", function()
    {        
      var i = 0;
     var j = 0;
      var found = [];
      var myDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("js-plotly-plot")[0]
      var data = JSON.parse(document.querySelectorAll("script[type=\'application/json\']")[0].innerHTML);
      for (i = 0 ;i < data.x.data.length; i += 1) {
        for (j = 0; j < data.x.data[i].text.length; j += 1) {
          if (data.x.data[i].text[j].indexOf(document.getElementById("inputText").value) !== -1) {
            found.push({curveNumber: i, pointNumber: j});
          }
        }
      }
      Plotly.Fx.hover(myDiv, found);
    }  
  );')))                                                    

htmlwidgets::saveWidget(p, paste('pca', ".html", sep=""))
p
```

**The code seems to run, but I do not see a search bar:**

[image]

**Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong and how I can fix this problem?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

#### Save as HTML

Probably the easiest route, when using Crosstalk, is to export through the Viewer pane in RStudio.

[image]

#### Add a Reset Button; Multiple Selection; Reduce Search Bar Size

Reset button: To add a reset option you'll need a bit of JS. (I'll come back to this in a bit.)

Multi-Select: To set this so that you select one or more items from the dropdown, in the call to filter_select, change the argument `multiple = F` to `T`.

Search Bar Width: You can set the width of the search bar as R code or in JS. For R, use the argument `widths` in the function `bscols`. Set a width for each item. The full width is always 12, so if you wanted the search bar to be half the width of the plot, but you wanted two rows, you could use `width = c(6, 12)`. (You'll get a warning if your `widths` total is over 12. It's just a warning, though.)

All of these examples assume that the ID in `filter_select` is `lantern`. If you change it in this function, you have to change it everywhere.

```
question_filter <- crosstalk::filter_select(
  "lantern", "Select a group to examine",
  sd, ~filterBy, multiple = T
)
```

##### Simplest Variation

This is bare bones but accomplishes what you want.

This requires the library `htmltools`.

```
bscols(widths = c(6, 6, 12),
       question_filter, 
       div(id = "yayButtons",
           tags$script(HTML(
             "setTimeout(function(){ 
             $('#yayButtons').append(         /* create and add button */
             '<button class=\"forStylin\" type=\"button\"' +
             'onClick=\"window.location.reload()\">' +  /* reset action */
             'Click Me to Reset Plot</button>');
             }, 10)"))),
       plot)
```

[image]

##### Alternate Search Bar Width Setting

If you wanted to set the width of the search bar with JS, you could add that to the plot with `htmlwidgets::onRender`. You could also add it to the `setTimeout` function in the middle. Here's an example with it attached to the plot (just so it's easier to see it).

```
bscols(widths = c(6, 6, 12),
       question_filter, 
       div(id = "yayButtons",
           tags$script(HTML(
             "setTimeout(function(){
             $('#yayButtons').append(         /* create and add button */
             '<button class=\"forStylin\" type=\"button\"' +
             'onClick=\"window.location.reload()\">' + /* reset action */
             'Click Me to Reset Plot</button>');
             }, 10)"))),
       plot %>% htmlwidgets::onRender(
         "function(){
         gimme = document.getElementById('lantern');
         gimme.style.width = '25%';       /* too small, but you get the point */
         }"))
```

[image]

##### Adding Styling to Reset Button

I know if I had a button and a search bar, I would want their appearances to at least to be somewhat similar. Here's a more complicated variation of the first version. This one adds styles to the reset button. I added quite a few things so you could see some of the options you have.

```
bscols(widths = c(6, 6, 12),
       question_filter, 
       div(id = "yayButtons",
           tags$script(HTML(
             "setTimeout(function(){
             $('#yayButtons').append(          /* create and add button */
             '<button class=\"forStylin\" type=\"button\"' +
             'onClick=\"window.location.reload()\">' + /* reset action */
             'Click Me to Reset Plot</button>');
             }, 10)")),
           tags$style(HTML(
             "div#yayButtons {     /* this centers the button in its area */
             display: flex;
             justify-content: center;
             }
             .forStylin {
             font-size: 1rem;    /* from input bar */
             font-family: times; /* from input bar */
             margin-top: 1rem;   /* inline with dropdown box */
             min-height: 34px;   /* attr of input box */
             background-color: rgb(31, 119, 180); /* plotly point color */
             color: white;
             }"
           ))),
       plot)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Kat! Will this code work for any type of plotly scatterplot in R?

Comment: As long as you use shared data, it shouldn't matter what type of plot it is.

Answer (score 1):

I adapted the answer from here and got something closer to what I was looking for:

```
library(plotly)
library(crosstalk)


dat <- tibble::tribble(~filterBy, ~x, ~y,
                       "a", 1, 1,
                       "b", 2, 1,
                       "a", 1, 2,
                       "b", 2, 2,
                       "a", 1, 3,
                       "b", 2, 3,
                       "a", 1, 2,
                       "b", 2, 3,
                       "c", 3, 1,
                       "c", 3, 2,
                       "c", 3, 3
)  


dat = data.frame(filterBy = 1:100, x = rnorm(100,100,100), y = rnorm(100,100,100))

sd <- SharedData$new(dat)

question_filter <- crosstalk::filter_select(
    "lantern", "Select a group to examine",
    sd, ~filterBy, multiple = F)  # <---- data changed to shared data


# Plotting:
plot <-  plot_ly(sd,  # <---- data changed to shared data
                 x = ~x, y = ~y, text = ~filterBy,  mode = "markers+text", 
                 textposition = "top", hoverinfo = "x+y")

plot
bscols(plot, question_filter) # combine crosstalk elements
```

[image]

Some questions still remain:

- Can this output be saved as an HTML file?
- Is it possible to add a "Reset Button"? (e.g. when I select a point, there is no way to go back to viewing all points)
- Is it possible to select multiple points?
- Is it possible to reduce the size of the search bar?